# Improving code design to enhance performance

Tags: java

I am trying to do something like below. I don't like the design of this as I am using 4 for loops to achieve this. Can I further enhance the design to achieve this?

1. Creating a map with dates as keys.
2. Sort the list values inside the map on dates(dates have hours and minutes here)
3. Giving an incremental id to each dto.

   ```
    int serialNumber = 1;
    if (hList != null && !hList.isEmpty()) {
        // create a Map with dates as keys
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<BookDTO>> mapObj = new HashMap<>();
        for (int count = 0; count < hList.size(); count++) {
            BookDTO bookDTO = (BookDTO) hList.get(count);

            ArrayList<BookDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(bookDTO);

            Calendar depDate = bookDTO.getDepartureDate();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            if (depDate != null) {
                String formattedDate = format.format(depDate.getTime());
                if (mapObj.containsKey(formattedDate)) {
                    mapObj.get(formattedDate).add(bookDTO);
                } else {
                    mapObj.put(formattedDate, list);
                }
            }

        }


    // Sort the values inside the map based on dates
    for (Entry<String, ArrayList<BookingDTO>> entry : mapObj.entrySet()) {
        Collections.sort(entry.getValue(), new BookDTOComparator(DATES));
    }

    for (Entry<String, ArrayList<BookDTO>> entry : mapObj.entrySet()) {
        serialNumber = setItinerarySerialNumber(entry.getValue(), serialNumber);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you can merge two last loops. So, we will see only two loops. (for now I can see three loops)
2. You can also try `Arrays.parallelSort(entry.getValue())` if lists are too large and it is applicable

Also, if it applicable, see code below:

```
int serialNumber = 1;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
ArrayList<BookDTO> hListCopy = new ArrayList<>(hList);
Collections.sort(hListCopy, new NewBookDTOComparator());               // 2. sorting
HashMap<String, ArrayList<BookDTO>> mapObj = new HashMap<>();
for (BookDTO bookDTO : hListCopy) {
    serialNumber = setItinerarySerialNumber(bookDTO, serialNumber);    // 3. serialNumber

    Calendar depDate = bookDTO.getDepartureDate();
    if (depDate != null) {
        String formattedDate = format.format(depDate.getTime());
        if (mapObj.containsKey(formattedDate)) {
            mapObj.get(formattedDate).add(bookDTO);
        } else {
            ArrayList<BookDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(bookDTO);
            mapObj.put(formattedDate, list);
        }
    }
}
```

So, only one loop (and one sorting algorithm).
For list cope-constructor used `System.arraycopy` internally, you can google performance of.

0. You can sort hList instead without creating new 'hListCopy' if applicable.
1. Beware of `NewBookDTOComparator`, you should sort not only by minutes and hours, but also by 'DepartureDate'
2. I think `SimpleDateFormat format` should be static field or class field.
3. You can also try `Arrays.parallelSort(hListCopy)` if lists are too large and it is applicable